# ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync - Throwing Access Denied exception

Tags: c#, casting, uwp, projection

ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync api is throwing exception.
**What i need?**
I have a uwp app. On button click i need to select a miracast device and connect to it and project a new view to it(or a page).
**OS: Windows 10 ,Versio 1709(OS build 16299.492)**

```
projectorSelectorQuery = "(System.Devices.DevObjectType:= 5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:= \"{0407d24e-53de-4c9a-9ba1-9ced54641188}\" AND System.Devices.WiFiDirect.Services:~=\"Miracast\")";
```

So only miracast devices will be visible.

```
var outputDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(projectorSelectorQuery);
```

I selected a miracast device and started projecting to it.

```
if (ProjectionViewPageControl == null)
        {
            // First, create a new, blank view
            var thisDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
            await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                // ViewLifetimeControl is a wrapper to make sure the view is closed only
                // when the app is done with it
                ProjectionViewPageControl = ViewLifetimeControl.CreateForCurrentView();

                // Assemble some data necessary for the new page
                var initData = new ProjectionViewPageInitializationData();
                initData.MainDispatcher = thisDispatcher;
                initData.ProjectionViewPageControl = ProjectionViewPageControl;
                initData.MainViewId = thisViewId;

                // Display the page in the view. Note that the view will not become visible
                // until "StartProjectingAsync" is called
                var rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), initData);
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

                // The call to Window.Current.Activate is required starting in Windos 10.
                // Without it, the view will never appear.
                Window.Current.Activate();
            });
        }

        try
        {
            // Start/StopViewInUse are used to signal that the app is interacting with the
            // view, so it shouldn't be closed yet, even if the user loses access to it
            ProjectionViewPageControl.StartViewInUse();

            // Show the view on a second display that was selected by the user

            await ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync(ProjectionViewPageControl.Id, thisViewId, selectedDisplay);
            ProjectionViewPageControl.StopViewInUse();
        }
        //catch(InvalidOperationException)
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            var msg = new MessageDialog(exception.Message + " Stack: " + exception.StackTrace + " Source: " + exception.Source);
           await msg.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Actually what happens is it will connect to miracast device- means my screen is mirrored to it.but my page is not projected.

[I am getting this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyHbe.jpg)

Comment: I noticed that your code is from the official [Projection sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection). If you directly test the official code sample to see if you still get the exception?

Comment: Yes, I am getting exception.@Xavier Xie -MSFT

Comment: If the official code sample did not work on your side. Your environment might have some problems. Please try to use other Projection app(not UWP app) to see if it will work.